# Dropdownlist value is not getting selected.

Tags: php

Below is my code. It is Editor for user profile page as admin. I want to show to as selected. I read answers here. I tried, but it's not working for me. Whenever it comes close, it shows me BLANK in dropdown list.

```
<select name="city"> 
<?php
    foreach( $province_array as $name)
    {
        if($name == $city )
        {
            echo '<option '.'value="'.$name.'"'.'selected="selected"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<option '.'value="'.$name.'"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

and here

```
$city = $row['city'];
```

Suggestions plz!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a few more spaces here. Change this:

```
echo '<option'.'selected="selected"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
```

to this for example:

```
echo '<option '.'selected="selected"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
```

Comment: still not giving me $city match select

Comment: Is there enough space between the tags?

Comment: You should add one more before the selected=

Comment: Thankx for All about this right coding but still I am not gettin Required Field for city

Comment: generated Html showing those option like this <option value="KUNDIAN"> … </option>i am beginner i can assume that it is Not printing Name of Values What i Am missing?

Comment: If none of them contains selected=something then probably there is an issue with the $city variable. You should print it somewhere to check.

Comment: No i got it Actually value when i was inputting in the form I was putting like i 2 3 4 then i manually inserted Names so its was only giving me 3 As $city and $name was number means int number Anyways Thankx for taking my attention towards inspect elements :) Thankx :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is put a space between the opening of your `<option>` tag and the `selected` attribute.  Check our your HTML source in the browser after you page has rendered.

```
<select name="city"> 
    <?php
       foreach( $province_array as $name)
       {
        if($name == $city )
        {
        echo '<option'.' selected="selected"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
        }
        else
        {
         echo '<option'.' value="'.$name.'".'>'.$name.'</option>';
        }
    }
       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statements are poorly constructed. There's no spaces between tag names and attributes. Try:

```
if($name == $city )
    {
    echo '<option selected="selected">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    else
    {
     echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option'.'selected="selected"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
```

here option and selected is not seperated. You can insert a blank btw them :

```
echo '<option'.' selected="selected"'.'>'.$name.'</option>';
```

make it for others too

Answer (score 0):

Appending a string that way always features a high level of risk that you may forget a space somewhere so I personally think that putting a string that needs single quotes inside double quotes like this:

```
echo "<option selected='selected'>".$name."</option>";
```

This makes it look so much more like normal HTML